# Can't decrypt with node.js v0.10.18 @ Windows 7 64Bit

Tags: node.js, encryption, windows-7, cryptography

I can't get `crypto` to work.

- windows 7 64Bit
- node.js v0.10.18

Encryption seems to work:

```
var fs = require('fs');

var img = new Buffer (fs.readFileSync('./image.png'), 'binary');

var crypto = require('crypto')
   , key = 'salt_from_the_user_document'
   , plaintext = img
   , cipher = crypto.createCipher('aes-256-cbc', key)
   , decipher = crypto.createDecipher('aes-256-cbc', key);

cipher.update(plaintext, 'binary', 'base64');
var encryptBinary = cipher.final('base64')
console.log('encrypted :', encryptBinary);
```

... but decryption not.

```
decipher.update(encryptBinary, 'base64', 'binary');
var decryptBinary = decipher.final('binary');
console.log('decrypted :', decryptBinary);
```

Same decryption problem with [node-efs](https://github.com/kunklejr/node-efs).

```
var efs = require('efs').init('aes-128-cbc', 'password');

// encrypt and write file
efs.writeFileSync('/tmp/example', 'hello world');

// decrypt and read file
efs.readFileSync('/tmp/example');
```

Same problem with [file-encryptor](https://npmjs.org/package/file-encryptor).

This works (with strings only):

```
var crypto = require('crypto')
 , key = 'salt_from_the_user_document'
 , plaintext = 'password'
 , cipher = crypto.createCipher('aes-256-cbc', key)
 , decipher = crypto.createDecipher('aes-256-cbc', key);

cipher.update(plaintext, 'utf8', 'base64');
var encryptedPassword = cipher.final('base64')

decipher.update(encryptedPassword, 'base64', 'utf8');
var decryptedPassword = decipher.final('utf8');

console.log('encrypted :', encryptedPassword);
console.log('decrypted :', decryptedPassword);
```

Answer (score 0):

The call to `update` also returns encrypted data, the call to `final` only returns the rest. Hence you need to concatenate output of each call to `update` and finally add the output of `final`. This is true for encryption as well as for decryption (and hashing, by the way).

Hence it needs to be something such as:

```
var encrypted = cipher.update(plaintext, 'binary', 'base64');
encrypted += cipher.final('base64');
```

Then it'll work.

Please note that the `update` and `final` functions are deprecated and the crypto module is now also stream-based and you might want to switch to the more modern approach anyway.

Comment: Thanks Golo for your fast reply. Encryption works. But not decryption.

Comment: var decrypted = cipher.update(plaintext, 'base64', 'binary');'
decrypted += decipher.final('binary');

Comment: [screenshot](https://s3-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/uploads-eu.hipchat.com/56830/387870/ee6ndrbskk5apca/cryptojs.png)

Comment: Could you please provide a [short, but complete sample program](http://www.yoda.arachsys.com/csharp/complete.html) that I can run to repeat your problem?